# Eclipse cannot connect oracle 10g XE on windows 7

Tags: eclipse, oracle-apex

Eclipse is not able to connect to oracle 10g it is giving errors like:

```
Could not connect to New Oracle.
Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to New Oracle. (Error: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call)
Io exception: Got minus one from a read call
Error creating jdbc.connection.name connection to New Oracle. (Error: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call)
Io exception: Got minus one from a read call
```

But it is opening the database page normally. I can create tables, insert, etc.

My url is `http://localhost:8080/apex`.

I used the following connection settings in Eclipse:

- SID: XE
- Host: localhost
- Port no: 8080
- Username: system
- password: 123
- Connection url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8080:XE

I have also started all Oracle services from services.msc.

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: The default port is 1521. Have you installed Oracle XE on a different port?

Answer (score 2):

Port 8080 is not for the Oracle database itself, it is for viewing Oracle Application Express (Apex) via a web browser.

I'm guessing you want Eclipse to connect to the database itself, so your JDBC URL should use port 1521 instead of 8080:

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer.
To fix this 
Go to SQL prompt type in "LSNRCTL SERVICES"
this gives you a block of code look for "PORT=XXXXX" key word.
its not always 1521. mine port '49160' instead of 1521 (surprisingly).

use : "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:XXXXX:ORCL";