# Oracle eclipse connection

Tags: eclipse, oracle, database-connection

I am absolutely new to oracle.
I am using oracle 10g connection and just on experimental basis trying to connect to HR schema, through the database explorer.
After much difficulty I figured SID, hostname etc, but now m stuck again.

Now I'm trying to establish a connection to the Database via eclipse but the ping keeps failing and get the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not
>   establish the connection  at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:257)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:389)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:454)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:165)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
>     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802)   at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:206)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.oracle.JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.java:27)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:355)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
>     at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a Network Adapter could not establish the connection, you have either the wrong SQL Developer URL or you have a basic SQL*Net connectivity issue!  This error is most likely caused by one of these factors:

- You are using the wrong URL
- The wrong port number or IP address (or DNS host name) was used
- The listener is not configured properly
- The listener process (service) is not running.  You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start" command or on Windows by starting the listener service.

Please refer [this link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=620751) for more detatils

Comment: I tried this, with help of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452115/not-able-to-connect-oracle-10g-xe-to-eclipse).Did not work